# Set variable from user selection in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, variables, set, sapb1

I am beginner in SQL Server

My query in SAP B1 is

```
  DECLARE @FROMDATE AS DATETIME
  SET @FROMDATE= [%0]

  DECLARE @TODATE AS DATETIME
  SET @TODATE= [%1]

  DECLARE @ACCNUM AS NVARCHAR(100)
  SET @ACCNUM= [%2]
```

get the account name, number for every transaction of an account

```
   SELECT 
   T4.[ACCOUNT] AS 'A/C NUM',
   T4.[ACCTNAME] AS 'A/C NAME',
   T4.[TransId] AS 'KEY',

   SUM(VEL_DB) AS 'VEL DB',
   SUM(VEL_CR) AS 'VEL CR',

   SUM(DEF_DB) AS 'DEF_DB',
   SUM(DEF_CR) AS 'DEF CR',
   T4.[LINEMEMO],
   T1.[U_Naaration]


   FROM OJDT T1
```

for every transaction in an account depending on the ocrcode2 credits and debits are calculated

```
   INNER JOIN 
      (
     SELECT T2.[TRANSID],T2.[ACCOUNT],T3.[ACCTNAME],T2.[LINEMEMO],

     case
     when T2.[OcrCode2]='VEL'
     THEN
       (T2.[Debit]) 
     ELSE
       NULL
     END as VEL_DB,

    case
    when T2.[OcrCode2]='VEL'
    THEN
     (T2.[CREDIT]) 
    ELSE
     NULL
    END as VEL_CR,

   case
   when T2.[OcrCode2]='' OR T2.[OCRCODE2] IS NULL
   THEN
     (T2.[Debit]) 
   ELSE
     NULL
   END as DEF_DB,

   case
   when T2.[OcrCode2]='' OR T2.[OCRCODE2]IS NULL
   THEN
       (T2.[CREDIT]) 
   ELSE
     NULL
   END as DEF_CR


   FROM JDT1 T2 
      INNER JOIN OACT T3 ON T3.[ACCTCODE]=T2.[ACCOUNT]
    where T2.[DUEDATE]>=@FROMDATE AND T2.[DUEDATE]<=@TODATE ) 
    T4 ON T4.TRANSID = T1.TRANSID AND T4.[ACCOUNT]=@ACCNUM


  GROUP BY T4.[TransId] ,T1.[U_Naaration],T4.[ACCTNAME],T4.[ACCOUNT],T4.[LINEMEMO]

   FOR BROWSE
```

I'm getting the error

> must select a table to select from

Answer (score 0):

As per the correct answer by Petr Verner [here](https://scn.sap.com/message/7293272), you may need to rewrite your query to avoid using a subquery.

The answer also goes on to suggest options:

1. Embed the query into a stored procedure and call that SP instead.
2. Use a view. (You could use it either for the subquery part or for the entire query).
3. Store the results of a subquery into a table variable (or into a temporary table), and then use the saved result set in the main query.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Andriy M. with ur suggestions my query is working well, due to creation of temporary table drill down is not possible. yellow colored arrow is not coming for my accounts and transactions. can you give me a solution for that.