# SAP query Must Specify Table to Select From

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, hana, sapb1

I have a query that works on SQL Server but not on SAP and I tried putting it on a SP so it can work but it doesn't. I want to limit the query by warehouse and a max date.

```
SELECT
MIN(c.GroupCode) AS 'GroupCode',
MIN(oitb.ItmsGrpNam) AS 'GroupName',
MIN(c.Wh) AS 'Warehouse',
SUM(c.balance) AS 'Total items',
SUM(c.value) AS 'Total price',
SUM(c.totalvalue) AS 'Total revenue',
SUM(c.mes) AS 'Menor a 30 días',
SUM(c.dos) AS 'Entre 30 a 60 días',
SUM(c.tres) AS 'Entre 60 a 90 días',
SUM(c.mas) AS 'Mayor a 90 días'
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    b.code, 
    b.GroupCode,
    b.Wh, 
    b.balance, 
    b.value,
    (b.balance * b.value) AS 'totalvalue',
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN b.days < 30 THEN b.balance END,0) 'mes' ,
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN b.days BETWEEN 30 AND 60 THEN b.balance END,0) 'dos',
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN b.days BETWEEN 60 AND 90 THEN b.balance END,0) 'tres',
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN b.days > 180 THEN b.balance END, 0) 'mas'

    FROM (
        SELECT 
        a.code,
        a.GroupCode,
        a.wh,
        a.balance,
        a.value,
        DATEDIFF(dd,dt,GETDATE())'days'
        FROM (
            SELECT 
            max(oinm.itemcode)'Code',
            max(oitm.ItmsGrpCod) 'GroupCode',
            max(oinm.Warehouse) 'Wh',
            sum(oinm.inqty-oinm.outqty) 'Balance',
            sum(oinm.transvalue) 'Value',
            max(oinm.docdate) 'dt'
            FROM oinm  
            INNER JOIN oitm on oinm.itemcode=oitm.itemcode
            WHERE oinm.warehouse= '[%0]' 
            AND oinm.DocDate <= '[%1]'
            GROUP BY oinm.itemcode
        )a
    )b 
)c
JOIN 
oitb
ON 
oitb.ItmsGrpCod = c.GroupCode
GROUP BY GroupCode
```

The SP (which has the same select) retrieves the same error. I tried the SP as suggested on [Set variable from user selection in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342333/set-variable-from-user-selection-in-sql-server)

```
DECLARE @Fd AS DATE;
DECLARE @whs AS VARCHAR;

SET @Fd = (SELECT '[%0]')
SET @whs = (SELECT '[%1]')

EXECUTE RotationByMaxDay (@Fd, @whs)
```

Comment: on the inner query (A) why are you grouping by oinm.itemcode and getting the max?  seems very odd to do both.

Comment: If you group by something, SQL server forces you to use a agg funcion. MySQL that's doesn't need that.

Comment: Typically when using aggregates, all non-aggregated fields in the select must be in the group by.    So if you aggregate all fields, you need no group by.   But in this case you have aggregated all the selected fields. Either you don't need the max on oinm.itemcode, or you don't need the max on that field in the select.  But I don't know if that's what is causing the issue.  Also SAP isn't a database.  Oralce, Hana, SQL server, Sybase  are all examples of databases on which SAP could run.  SAP is just the company/application

Comment: The problem is not the query itself. It works perfectly on SQL Server if I put it. To test on SQL server I use different values. The  '[%0]' and '[%1]' are SAP inputs on which I have the problem because SAP doesn't recognize what to ask.

Comment: would't your set statements be for the actual values being passed in? a valid date and a whs? not the variables used to hold them that are in the rotationbymaxday query?  it also seems odd the query would be using these variables as strings `'[%0]'` is a string datatype not a variable..  usually I see `@` for variables in SQL server.

Comment: The SP is a workaround I tried in order that the query worked for SAP. The problem is SAP that doesn't know what to do.  SAP doesn't even ask the user input field values on its query generator. The query is fine by itself. The SET statements are another try on what I read on other forums to try to execute de procedure on SAP and it works on other procedures I have but not on this one because I think the subquery is not well parsed on SAP's query gen.

Comment: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1953709?  is SAP defaulting values not provided to 0?